# Enabling scrolling in AChartEngine timechart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm just testing a time chart for AChartEngine with android. My current chart uses the code found here:
[how to implement TimeChart in achartengine with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869854/how-to-implement-timechart-in-achartengine-with-android/9030140#9030140)
this makes a time graph fine it works except it does not scroll.
the line
       mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true)
should make it scrollable (or panable) as i understand it but it does not seem to work. I've tried both changing it to        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true) and removing it alltogether however no matter what i do the graph doesn't allow me to scroll in any direction. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is it! My problem was i had setClickEnabled to true, thanks a bunch!