# using remove(int index) function for an XYSeries in aChartEngine

Tags: android, android-asynctask, achartengine

I am writing a code in which the graph must be continiously updated by repeatedly calling the aSyncTask. but to ensure thet the graph doesnot get too compressed, I plan to **remove/ delete the oldest entry** beyond a point.
Presently my code is as follows:

```
int counter = 0;
private class UpdateLineGraphAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // add the next series value
        series.add(counter, Math.sin((double) counter / 100));
        counter += 20;
        if (counter > 500)
            series.remove(0);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ((GraphicalView) lineGraph).repaint(); // repaints the graph!
    }

}
```

But this code keeps giving me a **null point exception** when i call remove(0); Can anyone explain how the function XYSeries.remove(index) works? I read somewhere that it is a LIFO structure. is this true? How to correct this error? even a single call of the remove function gives an error.

The error codes are:

```
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getY(XYSeries.java:169)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.initRange(XYSeries.java:83)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.remove(XYSeries.java:140)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.clearbridgevitalsigns.cardioleaf.LiveView$UpdateLineGraphAsync.doInBackground(LiveView.java:121)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at com.clearbridgevitalsigns.cardioleaf.LiveView$UpdateLineGraphAsync.doInBackground(LiveView.java:1)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-03 17:27:36.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1229):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you please give exact exception?

Comment: .....doInBackground(LiveView.java:121) refers to the series.remove(0) line

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same issue.
I didn't know why but I'm suppose it's due to concurrent access to series data from achartengine.
i managed to avoid this issue using another method to move the display, using renderer.setXAxisMin et renderer.setXAxisMax without working on the series themselves.

Answer (score 0):

First remove 0th element if collection exceeds limit and then try to add new element.

Comment: Can you please give me exact exception?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this NullPointerException is because of series.remove(0) statement. It works fine in my prototype. My view is you need to add your XYSeries in XYMultipleSeriesDataset. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869854/how-to-implement-timechart-in-achartengine-with-android) for example.